# Oracle SQL Developer: Tables?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I just installed my oracle database and made some tables for school. My problem is that it looked kind of different because the one we use in school had no tables(clean and empty) but the one that I had installed is filled with tables that I do not understand(I did not make them either).

It is a new install I got from the official website and it had tables named like: AQ$_INTERNET_AGENT_PRIVS, AQ$QUEUES and much more. I have no idea where they come from and every time I go look at my tables I just get confused because of all these things mixed in.

Is it safe to remove them or are they important enough to keep? If removing them is a bad idea, what do I have to do so that I don't see them anymore and all that is listed are the tables that I have created myself?

Answer (score 1):

Those are system tables, you're probably logging in to an account with DBA privileges. Create yourself a new schema (user_id/password) and don't give yourself dba privileges, then you can remain as ignorant as you want about what Oracle is doing under the hood.

Comment: What kind of privileges do I need to be able to do DDL and DML commands without seeing oracles own db?

Comment: Well, I'm not a DBA so take with a grain of salt. This is what I have used to create a schema in OracleXE: 
    create user YOUR_USERNAME identified by YOUR_PASSWORD;
    grant connect, resource to YOUR_USERNAME;